# Can I put a try-catch in GUI initialization code?

Tags: matlab, error-handling, matlab-guide

I am building a GUI in MATLAB (2016a) which I will be compiling and deploying. I want to try to do some global error handling, and it occurs to me that any command given to the GUI (button click, etc) first goes through the main initialization code before going to the specific Callback function. My thought was to put a `try-catch` block around the calls to `gui_mainfcn`. What's making me hesitate is that the code is bookended by some big old warnings:

```
% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
... initialization code here ...
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
```

Could I break something by putting a `try-catch` block inside this initialization section? Is there a better way to attempt global error handling for a single GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason that you can't insert global error handling in the main function of your GUIDE GUI. The warnings are really there to prevent people from inadvertently disrupting GUI functionality. In your case, a `try`/`catch` isn't going to actually *modify* the functionality so you're fine. You just want to be sure to not remove the calls to `gui_mainfcn` which is an internal function which contains all of the GUI logic.

Aside from that, you will also want to ensure that all requested output arguments are populated so that in the case of an error (for a function call where an output argument is expected) no error (within your `catch` block) is thrown *because of that*. That should be easy enough though

Also, I would only wrap the calls to `gui_mainfcn`

```
try
    if nargout
        [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
    else
        gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
    end
catch ME
    % Go ahead and fill in the requested outputs with [] so we don't get an error
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = deal([]);

     % Do special error handling here
    fprintf('Caught error: %s\n', ME.message);
end
```